Visual Studio RegEx search replace
I am not the best at regex, but trying to do a global search replace in Visual Studio of something like this
Url.Action(MVC.Administration.Administration.Index())

with
/Administration/Administration/Index

The logic is fairly simple in my head
You are basically

Replace Url.Action(MVC. with /
Replace ()) with nothing
Replace . with /


You could try this (js compatible) or this (pcre compatible) based on which regex flavor is Visual Studio using.

Use regex: https://regexper.com/#%2FUrl%5C.Action%5C%28MVC%5C.%28%5Cw%2B%29%5C.%28%5Cw%2B%29%5C.%28%5Cw%2B%29%5C%28%5C%29%5C%29%2F

Replace:
Url\.Action\(MVC\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\(\)\)

With
/$1/$2/$3

Tested in VS Code
